# Python for loops for noob

Tags: python

I'm taking the MIT 6 Programming with Python course for kicks and for a problem set everyone, teach included, wrote their for loop like this:

```
s="whataboutbob"
for char in range(len(s)):
```

Isn't that the same as:

```
s="whataboutbob"
 for char in s:
```

why would someone use the range and len functions if you can just use the variable?  What am I missing?  I'd ask them but im doing the course solo and the forums are empty-ish. Thanks.

Comment: Search for range function in python there you will find your answer.

Comment: Try executing the python codes of the examples you have in your course.

Answer (score 3):

They're not the same thing.

```
for char in s:
    print(char)
```

Will print the characters in `s`. I.e 'w', 'h', 'a', etc.

```
for n in range(len(s)):
    print(n)
```

Will print the *numbers* 0, 1, 2, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do some sort of operation with the indices of a list or a string in python, then you would use the `range` function. In that sense, iterating over a range provides more flexibility.

Another alternative when using a for loop is using the `enumerate` function. If you were to write

```
s="whataboutbob"
for n, char in enumerate(s):
```

then in your loop you would be able to use the variable `n` to refer to the index in the string, and the variable `char` to refer to the actual character at that index.

Answer (score 0):

for char in range(len(s)): iterates over numbers from zero to length of string, another loop iterates over characters of string: w,h,a,t,... It is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The `len()` function takes the number of characters that you are currently on, starting from 0. For instance in `apple`, the *a* would be 0, the *p* would be 1 etc.

On the other hand

```
for char in (variable):
    print char
```

would print each letter in that variable, so like 
*a-p-p-l-e*.

Answer (score 0):

It is **NOT** the same thing:

```py
s="whataboutbob"
for char in s:
    print(char)
```

Would give us a result of

```
w
h
a
t
a
b
o
u
t
b
o
b
```

whilst

```py
s="whataboutbob"
for char in range(len(s)):
    print(char)
```

would give us this result:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```